# Is there a way I can update mongodb document without a loop ie. with array as condition?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

> this is my document

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef05c35743df0112cbf5729"), 
"doctor" : ObjectId("5e2ef5fd55e8c1043895aaf1"), 
"patient" : ObjectId("5e0378d9a88e67364426be55"), 
"requests" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5ef05c35743df0112cbf572d"), 
                 "labTestType" : ObjectId("5ee752b9e26cbb3440b9259e"), 
                 "result" : "", 
                 "paymentstatus" : "Unpaid", 
                 "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T07:22:29.664Z"), 
                 "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T07:22:29.664Z") }, 
               { "_id" : ObjectId("5ef05c35743df0112cbf572c"), 
                 "labTestType" : ObjectId("5ee752b9e26cbb3440b925a6"), 
                 "result" : "", 
                 "paymentstatus" : "Unpaid", 
                 "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T07:22:29.664Z"), 
                 "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T07:22:29.664Z") }, 
               { "_id" : ObjectId("5ef05c35743df0112cbf572b"), 
                 "labTestType" : ObjectId("5ee752b9e26cbb3440b925b5"), 
                 "result" : "", 
                 "paymentstatus" : "Unpaid", 
                 "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T07:22:29.664Z"), 
                 "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T07:22:29.664Z") }, 
               { "_id" : ObjectId("5ef05c35743df0112cbf572a"), 
                 "labTestType" : ObjectId("5ee752b9e26cbb3440b925b6"), 
                 "result" : "", 
                 "paymentstatus" : "Unpaid", 
                 "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T07:22:29.664Z"), 
                 "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T07:22:29.664Z") } 
             ], 
"createdAt" : ISODate("2020-06-22T07:22:29.664Z"), 
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-06-23T06:35:06.420Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

> I want to update paymentstatus under requests to Paid by providing labTestType
> Objectids as list of array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code this works for me

```
    db.getCollection('your_collection').findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        $and: [
          { _id: new ObjectId(_id) },  //_id = "5ef05c35743df0112cbf5729"
          { 'requests.labTestType': { $in: [new ObjectId('5ee752b9e26cbb3440b9259e'), new ObjectId('5ee752b9e26cbb3440b925b5')] } }]
      },
      {
        $set: { 'requests.$.paymentstatus': 'paid' 
      } //set new payment status
  })
```

Comment: thanks. but i want to provide the labTestType ObjectId as array like this [5ee752b9e26cbb3440b9259e, 5ee752b9e26cbb3440b925b5] and update morethan one field at a time.

Comment: thanks Mayur Vaghasiya the $in property from your code helped a lot

Comment: and also can you help to update the results, provided that the coming results are arrays of string like this [a,b,c,d,e,f]

Comment: In my code i use `findOneAndUpdate`. so its return only one object.

Answer (score 0):

> this worked for me i was missing $in property

```
db.getCollection('your_collection').updateMany(
        {_id: newObjectId(_id)},
        {$set: {"requests.$[element].paymentstatus": "Paid"}},
        { multi:true,
          arrayFilters: [{ "element.labTestType": {$in: arraywithobjectIds}}]
        })
```